# vector<float>* causing seg fault!

Tags: c++

I have a vector of floats, defined by:

```
std::vector<float>* MyVec;
```

and I was filling this inside a for loop later with:

```
MyVec->push_back(somevalue)
```

and I was getting a seg fault.  In order to try and find out what was going on I commented out the push_back line and I still saw a seg fault, and when it seg faulted the size of MyVec was 490618047.

Is there perhaps something I have forgotten to do with this vector, and how is it getting filled by such a huge number without any entries being entered into the vector?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the whole piece of code. If my guess is correct, there is no vector at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've not allocated memory:

```
std::vector<float>* MyVec = new std::vector<float>();
```

Because `MyVec` is a *pointer* to `std::vector<float>`, you've to do the above, before using `MyVec`.

Also, don't forget to deallocate the memory, once you're done with `MyVec`:

```
delete MyVec;
```

Apart from that, *I think*, you don't need a *pointer* to begin with; if so, then you should do the following instead of declaring a pointer:

```
std::vector<float> MyVec; //it is NOT a pointer.
```

And use it as:

```
MyVec.push_back(someFloatValue);
```

Answer (score 11):

You created a pointer to a `std::vector<float>`. If you do not initialize it

```
std::vector<float>* MyVec = new std::vector<float>();
```

it will point to some random memory location and be unusable.

Maybe you don't even need to use a pointer.

```
std::vector<float> MyVec;
MyVec.push_back(somevalue)
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you allocate any storage for the pointer to `std::vector<float>` you declared?

```
// declares a pointer to a vector of float
std::vector<float>* myvec;

// will segfault here
myvec->push_back(0.0);

// need to create this vector dynamically
std::vector<float>* myvec = new std::vector<float>();

// now you can push_back
myvec->push_back(0.0);

// when you're done with it
delete myvec;
```

Without seeing any more code, that is the problem in a nutshell.  I would question whether you need to dynamically allocate your vector, and if so I would advise using an appropriate smart pointer for that task.

Answer (score 5):

You should initialize it like this:

```
std::vector<float>* MyVec = new std::vector<float>();
```

Do not forget to delete it later on:

```
delete MyVec;
```

Or you wrap it in a smart pointer (e.g. from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm))